# Did I use Stirling formula incorrectly?

Tags: analysis

I have to prove that $\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n} * e^{-n}*n^k}{k!}  \to e^{-x^2/2}$ when $\frac{k-n}{\sqrt{n}} \to x$ and $n \to \infty$

I used Stirling formula and get that $\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n} * e^{-n}*n^k}{k!} = e^{k-n} * (n/k)^k \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{\sqrt{2\pi k}}$

From $\frac{k-n}{\sqrt{n}} \to x$ we get that $n/k \to 1$
than $\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{\sqrt{2\pi k}} \to 1$

So we get $e^{k-n} * (n/k)^k$

But $(n/k)^k = (1 + (n-k)/k)^{k/(n-k) * (n-k)} = e^{n-k}$ because $(n-k) / k \to 0$

So everything tends to $e^{k-n} * e^{n-k} = 1$

What do I do wrong?(

Comment: Use `$\to$` for $\to$ and `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: In fact, [here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Also note that a single line break in the input box has the same effect as a single blank space when the question is formatted. That is another effect that makes your question hard to read. Try putting an extra blank line between the lines of input text when you want to start a new paragraph.

Comment: Thanks:) I've edited my question

Comment: "Using Stirling formula" Which one?
"Stirling formula" is an asympotic approximation, but in that line you wrote an equality, that does not look right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a mistake: $$\left(1+\frac{n-k}{k}\right)^{\frac{k}{n-k}\cdot(n-k)}\sim e^{n-k}$$Is not true, because the $(n-k)$ exponent complicates things: because it is growing while $(n-k)/k$ is decreasing, and the relative rates of growth do matter. To explain what I mean, if $a$ is constant then it is true that: $$\left(1+\frac{n-k}{k}\right)^{\frac{k}{n-k}\cdot a}\sim e^a$$But here, $a=n-k$ is not constant, and it is *a priori* unclear what the asymptotic behaviour is.

Let's be more careful:

$$\begin{align}\left(1+\frac{n-k}{k}\right)^k&=\exp(k\log(1+(n-k)/k))\\&=\exp(k((n-k)/k-(n-k)^2/2k^2+\psi((n-k)/k)))\\&=\exp(n-k-(n-k)^2/2k+\psi((n-k)/k))\cdot k)\end{align}$$Where $\psi(y)\in\Theta(y^3)$ as $y\to0$. Since $n/k\to1$, $(n-k)/k\to0$ as $n,k\to\infty$ and $k\cdot((n-k)/k)^{3}=(n-k)^3/k^2\sim-x^3n\sqrt{n}/k^2\sim-x^3n^{-1/2}\to0$ thus $\psi((n-k)/k)\cdot k$ vanishes as $n,k\to\infty$.

So: $$e^{k-n}(n/k)^k=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{k-n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\cdot\frac{n}{k}+o(1)\right)\to e^{-x^2/2}$$

Therefore, combining with your other correct work, we have the result.

Comment: Omg, thanks. Now I understand!

Comment: @ЗахарНаумець You’re welcome!